# Check user activity in php login site

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect

I want to check if user has already been logged in, for example if the user has already logged in, and open login link again, should redirect him on index page, but my problem is, i have  php code in login site, and my php login site dont show, and I can not log in.

```
    <?php
   session_start(); //start session.
   if(!isset($_SESSION['User_id']) && $_SESSION['User_id'] == ""){
       header('Location: ../users/login.php?error=5'); //redirect URL
   }
   else{
       header('Location: ../users/index.php?error=6'); //session gestartet
       }
   ?>
```

index.php direct open error, and back to login site, works

```
<?

    php session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['User_id'])){ 
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
    $extra = '../users/login.php?error5'; // direct access error 
    header("Location: http://$host/$extra"); } 
    ?>
```

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmHvQ.png)

Comment: "_but my problem is, i have php code in login site_" Why is that a problem? Where does your code redirect to the index page?

Comment: problem is, if I want to log in me, login site dont show, what ist problem mit dem code oben

Comment: Regarding the `&&` (AND) operator. I am pretty sure you're looking for `||` (OR). Now, can you show us any other code for other related pages using sessions?

Comment: I have with || but no login page, do not show up, show me error

Comment: what error? Post the full error. Are you using error reporting also? Your question is unclear. Sessions are used for 2 or more pages. You showed us code for the one page only @Yoe

Comment: I do not want the user who signed in, anymore to login site open with link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting a redirect loop, so your logic is likely not sound, as noted by other users in relation to this line:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['User_id']) && $_SESSION['User_id'] == ""){
```

I imagine you probably have a similar line else where, especially if you say you have changed this line to use `||` instead of `&&`.

I would say it would be helpful to make your script(s) more human-readable with functions (or class/methods) so it's easier to use and keep consistent, here is just an example:

**/functions.php**

```
<?php
# Have a simple function to determine login state
function isLoggedIn()
{
    # Since $_SESSION['User_id'] must be filled to be logged in, empty() is the simplest
    # and best to use here because it takes care of isset() and == '' at the same time
    return (!empty($_SESSION['User_id']));
}
# Have a redirect function so you know it's going to be consistent
function redirect($to)
{
    header('Location: '.$to);
    exit;
}
# Maybe a site url is helpful
function baseUrl($path = false)
{
    return 'http://'.str_replace('//', '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$path);
}
```

**/restricted_page.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
# Add the functions
include(realpath(__DIR__.'/..').'/functions.php');
# If the user is not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn()) {
    # Redirect them to the login page
    redirect(baseUrl('users/login.php?error=5'));
}
```

**/users/login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
# Add the functions
include(realpath(__DIR__.'/..').'/functions.php');
# If the user is logged in already
if(isLoggedIn()) {
    # Redirect home since they don't need to log in again
    redirect(baseUrl());
}
```

Assuming that the index page is neutral, it shouldn't be redirecting anywhere. If your login page posts to a different page to check credentials, it would be something like:

**/users/process_login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
# Add the functions
include(realpath(__DIR__.'/..').'/functions.php');
# Check if the login has been submitted
if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    # Go back to login page if not
    redirect('users/login.php?error=7');
}
# Do your checking with whatever login code you use...
// code here...
# Check if the user is logged in now
if($success) {
    # Redirect to success page
    $page = 'success.php';
}
else {
    # Redirect back to login with failure msg
    $page = 'users/login.php?error=5';
}
# Redirect
redirect($page);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried code from you, works.
But I also found another solution